# Jenkins doesn't work on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I've tried setting up jenkins on some free-tier ec2 instances and despite jenkins running properly i am getting the below error after running curl localhost:8080.

```
**<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>
Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:
Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
</body></html>**
```

Appreciate help,please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not able to authenticate because you are not providing authentication details. Provide your jenkins user name and password
 curl -X POST http://username:password@localhost:8080/job/test/build

follow below links for more information. 
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218889337-How-to-build-a-job-using-the-REST-API-and-cURL-

https://jenkinsapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using_jenkinsapi.html#

If you wanted to use the jenkins from browser use your ec2 public ip or elastic ip   i.e, **PUBLIC_IP:8080**

Comment: With Public/Elastic IP,it doesn't load the page at all.I see a "page cant be displayed".Security groups,Subnets etc looks good.I am able to access http server outside of the instance without any issues (The only problem i see is with Jenkins url)

Comment: I found the root cause,it was my company network preventing from accessing jenkins,oops :(